# Reusing Git Branch

Tags: git, branch

I am new to Git but I do understand about Master and feature branch concepts. While having branch name for different feature makes sense but if we are working on a single developer, small scale app and getting review through pull request when *reasonable* amount of work has been done sounds reasonable, I find it redundant that I have to create a new feature branch whenever I integrate next iteration of features. I did attempt to reuse a branch but it caused conflict in pull request.

Should we just be creating  new branches every time new additions are done?

Comment: With torek's answer as a starting point: The question, I suppose, is why the PR got conflicts (and what to do to avoid that). Note that pull requests themselves are not a git concept, but rather a concept of "the other things around git" (usually github; or similar to "merge requests" in gitlab). Still, I would expect conflicts to be based on the merge or rebase operations that result from the PR. Diagnosing may require a more complete picture (e.g. commit graphs before/after 1st PR, and before 2nd PR, as a start) but generally I would second that reusing a branch shouldn't bother git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Git* has no problem with re-using or re-purposing branch names.  It's the other things *around* Git, including how people use Git and how various integration systems use Git, that have problems with re-using or re-purposing branch names.

As far as Git itself is concerned, a branch is literally just a string name for a commit hash ID, with a few special properties:

- The *full name* of this string starts with `refs/heads/`.  (Normally you see the string without the prefix.)
- The commit hash identified by the name is expected to change over time as new commits get added to the branch.
- In fact, it's *so* expected that Git will do this *automatically* for you, when you make a new commit while "on" the branch (as in, when `git status` says `on branch xyz`: then a new commit makes `xyz` name the new commit's hash).
- As a result, if someone else copies your branch name into their repository—typically as a *remote tracking branch name*—they too will expect to update this name, but sometimes only in a "fast forward" fashion.  That is they won't expect you to take the name `xyz` and make it refer to (the last of) a set of commits quite unrelated to the previous set of commits to which `xyz` referred.

If the other people (and processes) *do* all agree that `xyz` moves, perhaps radically, there is no problem repurposing `xyz` at that time.  If the other people *do not* agree, you will run into issues where they expect `xyz` not to change like this.  They may re-set `xyz` to the way *they* expected it to go, which will interfere with *your* re-setting of `xyz`.

In short, re-use is no problem *provided* everyone agrees in advance that re-use is no problem.  If no one else uses your names, you need only agree with yourself.  If others use your names too, make sure they are OK with this.